# In phoenix, how do upsert from select with group by and put the values of one column into an array column?

Tags: sql, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have two tables, one which is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE DESTINATION_TABLE (
  EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  UID UNSIGNED_LONG NOT NULL,
  SOURCES VARCHAR[],
  CONSTRAINT PK_DT PRIMARY KEY (EFFECTIVE_DATE,UID)
);
```

I want to upsert into this from another table with something like this (pseudo code):

```
UPSERT INTO DESTINATION_TABLE
SELECT
  EFFECTIVE_DATE,
  NEXT VALUE FOR CIBC_COPY.AUM_AGGREGATES_SEQ AS "UID",
  (SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT_ID) AS SOURCES
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
GROUP BY EFFECTIVE_DATE;
```

Is something like this possible in phoenix?

Answer (score 2):

You can do an upsert-select as specified in the phoenix documentation.

https://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html#upsert_select

> UPSERT INTO test.targetTable(col1, col2) SELECT col3, col4 FROM test.sourceTable WHERE col5 < 100
>   UPSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM bar;

This can also be used to update multiple rows in your table.In this case your source table and target table would be the same.

For eg you could do something like this

> UPSERT INTO FOO(RK,AGE,CITY,NAME) SELECT RK,AGE,CITY,REGEX_REPLACE('MATT','MATT','CARTER') FROM FOO WHERE NAME='MATT';

This will update the name from MATT to CARTER in all rows where the persons name is MATT.